# How to dynamically change css style based on INPUT value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dynamic

We have some data that user enters and the result after calculation. Now I want depending on the value that the user gets after calculation to change css style.

My html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
    .not_good { solid red; background:#eee;}
    .good { solid green; background:#C0E9F6;}
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var BuckwheatCa = 4

    function convcase(word) {
        document.convert.Ca.value = BuckwheatCa * document.convert.Buckwheat.value
    };
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <FORM ACTION="#" NAME="convert">
        Buckwheat, gramm
        <INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME="Buckwheat"
        ONKEYUP="convcase(document.convert.Buckwheat.value)" >
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Ca</td> <td><INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME="Ca" DISABLED></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </FORM>
</body>
</html>
```

so is there a way to create a function with if...else statement using **document.convert.Ca.value** variable value witch will change css style of text in <*td*> if the variable is < 10 for example?

Comment: What style you want to change of which `<td>`?

Comment: @Manwal He said he wants to change the style of the `<td>` based on the input in `Ca`.

Comment: I want to change text color in <td>Ca</td> and <td><INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME="Ca" DISABLED></td> @Manwal

Comment: You have a semicolon missing on this line: `document.convert.Ca.value = BuckwheatCa * document.convert.Buckwheat.value`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using normal javascript using this in your code

```
if(value<10){
       document.getElementById("sample").style.color="blue";
}
```

OR You can do it using jQuery:

```
if(value<10){
       $("sample").css("color","blue");
}
```

Choose whichever appeals to you.

Of course you must have IDs as @Barmar suggested:

```
<td id='sample'>Ca</td> <td><INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME="Ca" DISABLED></td>
```

The above code now changes the style of `Ca` alone as the id exists for that tag.

And you can make changes to any of the css properties: http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/css/propindex/all.htm

Comment: You should mention that he needs to give these elements IDs.

Answer (score 0):

```
function convcase(word) {
document.convert.Ca.value = BuckwheatCa * document.convert.Buckwheat.value
// now add css comparison
if(document.convert.Ca.value < 10){
    // using jQuery to access the 'td' and set the css on it
    $('td').css('font-family', 'arial');
} else {
    // whatever you want
}
};
```